# Change path to error views

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

From the documentation I see that I simply have to create new blade files within `resources/views/errors/` and call them using `abort(newhtmlerrorno)`

If I want to use blade files from another directory, is this possible or must they be in the base app `resources/views/errors/`

Answer (score 3):

In your `App\Exceptions\Handler` class, add this to the start of your render method:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($this->isHttpException($e)) {
        $statusCode = $e->getStatusCode();
        return view("custom.path.{$statusCode}");
    }

    // ...
}
```

The `error` folder on the view path is hardcoded in `Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler` class, which your local app `Handler` extends. So you can't just configure a custom path without overriding that particular class.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a way to do this without directly editing the laravel classes.

Comment: App\Exceptions\Handler:class is not a Laravel "vendor" class. Everything that resides within your App namespace is for you to edit. This is the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method \Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler::registerErrorViewPaths in Laravel 5.8. You can simply override it in your \App\Exceptions\Handler class:

```
protected function registerErrorViewPaths()
{
    $paths = collect(config('view.paths'));

    View::replaceNamespace('errors', $paths->map(function ($path) {
        return "{$path}/YOUR_CUSTOM_PATH/errors";
    })->push(__DIR__.'/views')->all());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

find file App\Exceptions\Handler and replce function render with below

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {
        $statusCode = $exception->getStatusCode();
        return response()->make(view("NEW_PATH.{$statusCode}",['exception'=>$exception]), $statusCode) ;
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```